# Why can we decompose Hermitian Matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

In my quantum physics class today, I learned about Hermitian Matrices decomposition. The process can be described as follows:

Decomposing Hermitian Matrices:

1. Find eigenvalues.
2. Find eigenvectors.
3. Find generator matrices using eigenvectors (where a generator matrix is defined as the outer product of an eigenvector with itself).
4. Find the decomposition using eigenvalues and generator matrices.

I would like to know what relationship between eigenvalues and generator matrices allows such a decomposition. Namely, why does the relationship

$$
[M] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\ {| i\rangle}  {\langle i|}
$$

hold?

note:
$[M] =$ the Hermitian matrix; $\lambda_i =$ eigenvalue;
${| i\rangle}  {\langle i|} =$ generator

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you have any basis $\mathbf v_1, \dots, \mathbf v_n$ of $\mathbb R^n$, you can define a linear transformation $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ simply by specifying $f(\mathbf v_1), \dots, f(\mathbf v_n)$.

---

If $\mathbf v_1, \dots, \mathbf v_n$ is an *orthonormal* basis, then $f$ has the matrix representation $f(\mathbf x) = M\mathbf x$ where
$$
   M = f(\mathbf v_1)\mathbf v_1^{\mathsf T} + \dots + f(\mathbf v_n) \mathbf v_n^{\mathsf T}.
$$
To check that this works, we can just take
$$M \mathbf v_i = f(\mathbf v_1)\mathbf v_1^{\mathsf T}\mathbf v_i + \dots + f(\mathbf v_i)\mathbf v_i^{\mathsf T}\mathbf v_i + \dots f(\mathbf v_n) \mathbf v_n^{\mathsf T}\mathbf v_i$$
and simplify: the term $f(\mathbf v_i)\mathbf v_i^{\mathsf T}\mathbf v_i$ simplifies to $f(\mathbf v_i)$, and all other terms simplify to $0$.

---

The key property of a symmetric matrix $M$ is that it has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors: there is an orthonormal basis $\mathbf v_1, \dots, \mathbf v_n$ of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $M \mathbf v_i = \lambda_i \mathbf v_i$ for $i=1, \dots, n$.

So if we define $f(\mathbf x) = M\mathbf x$, then $f(\mathbf v_i) = \lambda_i\mathbf v_i$ for $i=1, \dots, n$, and therefore we can write $M$ as
$$
   M = \sum_{i=1}^n f(\mathbf v_i) \mathbf v_i^{\mathsf T} = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \mathbf v_i \mathbf v_i^{\mathsf T}
$$
which is the decomposition you want.

If you replace $\mathbb R^n$ by $\mathbb C^n$, $\mathbf x^{\mathsf T}$ by the conjugate transpose, and "symmetric" by "Hermitian", all of this still holds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a sense of what you are saying. The language was bit more technical than I am used to, and I will have to come back and read again a few times to fully grasp the full meaning of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The crucial relationship between what you call generator matrices and the eigenvalues is that the generator matrices are orthogonal projections (namely $|i\rangle\langle i|$ projects onto the linear subspace spanned by $|i\rangle$) and $M$ acts as $\lambda_i$ times the identity on this subspace.

Once you know that every Hermitian matrix has at least one eigenvalue, this is enough to show this decomposition as follows. Let $\lambda_1$ be an eigenvalue of $M$ with corresponding normalized eigenvector $|1\rangle$. Knowing that $|1\rangle\langle 1|$ is the orthogonal projection onto the linear subspace spanned by $|1\rangle$, we can write
$$
M|=M(|1\rangle\langle 1|+I-|1\rangle\langle 1|)=\lambda_1|1\rangle\langle 1|+M(I-|1\rangle\langle 1|).
$$
Now $I-|1\rangle\langle 1|$ is the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of $|1\rangle$. Since $M$ is hermitian, this space is also invariant under $M$, or in other words, $M(I-|1\rangle\langle 1|)=(I-|1\rangle\langle 1|)M(I-|1\rangle\langle 1|)=:M_1$.

The matrix $M_1$ is again hermitian on the $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace $|1\rangle^\perp$. This means you can play the same game again: Find and eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ with corresponding normalized eigenvector $|2\rangle$ and write $M_1$ as
$$
M_1=\lambda_2|2\rangle\langle 2|+M_1(I-|2\rangle\langle 2|).
$$
Thus
$$
M=\lambda_1|1\rangle\langle 1|+M_1=\lambda_1|1\rangle\langle 1|+\lambda_2|2\rangle\langle 2|+M_1(I-|2\rangle\langle 2|).
$$
Note that in every step we reduce the dimension by $1$, so that after $n$ steps (if $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix) we arrive at
$$
M=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i|i\rangle\langle i|.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Your explanation was quite illuminating.